# MongoDB: Recommended schema for search in trees

Tags: mongodb, database-design

Currently I have a tree with various depth that contains user's documents.

John\folder1\sub-folder2...\document
Peter\folder1...\document

But as I can see Mongo does not support indexes in nested documents. 
I tried to de-normalize my DB to User\documents with children ids. But it seems search would search whole collection, not only documents for given app-user.

should I create collection for every app user?

What is the better solution to use built in Mongo aggregation methods?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use only one collection and not create collection for every user.

Using aggregation first thing you would do is a match by userId which filters all the documents by that user and then do any aggregation operations.

Aggregation in mongo is pipeline. Documents move from one operation to another.

So if you do match on userId then only those documents would be chosen and the next aggregation operation will get only those documents which matches the userId. So your aggregation is still faster.

Comment: Unfortunately I have rather small body of the document, and adding userId per entity would be expensive. Also building tree would be quite expensive operation.